# Progress bar for stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm calling a stored procedure from asp.net front-end. It usually do inserts on many tables. On the front-end I would like to show 2 things: Progress bar like how much is completed. The second thing to show is current database insertion. like: CURRENTLY INSERTING: tblCustomers

Appreciated!

Comment: ASP.NET is not Winforms. So it would be impossible to refresh the front-end without any periodically (ajax-)requests from the client. I think you need some kind of log table where you cache the insert-state. Then you can query this table to refresh the front-end.

Comment: This link might also be helpful: http://devarchive.net/displaying_progress_bar_for_long_running_processes.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll likely need a log table that your front-end would monitor the progress on. This would also require the existing stored proc to log an update to this table between different insert/statuses. Your front-end would need some ajax to query a total records to insert and currently inserted to get your progress bar.