# Create real time Progress bar winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

i am creating a windows application. On the click of button i execute a store procedure . The executing time of the Store procedure  may be take 1 min or may be 2 minutes or more time. So how can i show the progress bar for that time when my SP is executing . 
**Below is the code for button click**

```
 private void mnucollections_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_commonDAC == null)
             _commonDAC = new CommonDAC();
        if (MsgBox.Show("It is advised that you run Rebalance before entering Collection \n Run Rebalance now  ?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
             frmProgressBar progress = new frmProgressBar(LoginName);
             progress.ShowDialog();    
        }
        else
        {
            frmCollections co = new frmCollections(LoginName);
            co.ShowDialog();
        }
```

**on the Form where is my progress bar on form Load i write below code**

```
  private void frmProgressBar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (_commonDAC == null)
           _commonDAC = new CommonDAC();  

       this.ServiceProgressBar.Visible = true;
       int result = _commonDAC.RebalanceClient(); // Calling my store procedure 
       this.ServiceProgressBar.Visible = false;
        //progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;



    }
```

Comment: How do you intend to make your SP report its progress so that you can capture it? Or are you going to make it time-dependent like as you said it always takes 2 minutes at most?

Comment: @romar i give an example the sp may take 10 minutes or 1/2 an hours to successfully execution .

Comment: This means you are left with two options. 1. To set the ProgressBarStyle property of your progress bar to Marquee. This does not show real progress, but it only informs the user that the program is still active and is working on the task (no percentage of completion is shown). 2. Break down your stored procedure into several stages and report status back to your winform after each stage. One approach for doing this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447152/progress-bar-for-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Calling your stored procedure will prevent the `frmProgressBar_Load()` method from returning, which will keep the UI thread from running. You can address that with something like this:

```
private async void frmProgressBar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_commonDAC == null)
        _commonDAC = new CommonDAC();  

    this.ServiceProgressBar.Visible = true;

    // Calling my store procedure 
    int result = await Task.Run(() => _commonDAC.RebalanceClient());

    this.ServiceProgressBar.Visible = false;
    //progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
}
```

That way, the method will return after the task running the `RebalanceClient()` method is started, and then later when the task finishes, it will continue by assigning the result to `result` and executing the `this.ServiceProgressBar.Visible = false;` statement. Leaving the UI thread free to run in the meantime, of course.

Comment: What is `await Task.Run(() =>` here and how when i use  the code it give me error

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? You need VS2012 or later, or you need to install the compiler and library separately for .NET 4.0. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx. If you can't use that feature, there are other mechanisms that work similarly, just not as convenient. If you say what version of C#/.NET you're using, that would help.

Comment: i am using VS 2010 4.5 version

Comment: If you're using C# 5.0 and .NET 4.5 with VS2010, then the async stuff should work. What error are you getting?

Comment: i am noting getting any error but problem is that my the progress bar is not displaying that i want

Comment: So the comment you wrote -- "when i use the code it give me error" -- no longer applies? Now that you have the progress bar showing, but not displaying what you want, that's a separate question. Probably you don't have any code in your `RebalanceClient()` method that would (or maybe even could) update the progress. But a) there's nothing in the question here that gives enough information to address that, and b) it really is a different question IMHO.